# Proc command is not working on checking the inclusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a field called visit_time with two distinct values. They are "AM" and "PM"

I check the presence of the visit_time by the following validation syntax.

```
validates_presence_of :visit_time,
      message: "visit time is required"
```

Then I need to check the inclusion validation only if the visit_time is presence, for this I am using the Proc. But it is not working.

```
validates :visit_time,
        :inclusion  => { :in => [ 'AM', 'PM'],
                         :message    => "%{value} is not a valid time" },
        :if => Proc.new { |o| o.errors.empty? }
```

Let me know what's wrong on it. Is `Proc` is not working for inclusion ??? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the inclusion validation to run only if it's present, you should change the Proc to this instead:

```
if: Proc.new { |o| o.visit_time.present? }
```